# EF Core 6 Database First Parent Child Relation issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

We are building an application using .NET 6 and EF Core 6 with an existing SQL Server database. We are using the database first approach and running the Scaffold-DbContext tool we were able to generate the dbcontex class. Everything works fine, a part for a parent child relation between two tables:

[image]

The scaffold tool, for the above tables generated the following two classes:

```
public partial class TreeNode
    {
        public TreeNode()
        {
            TreeNodeHierarchyChildren = new HashSet<TreeNodeHierarchy>();
            TreeNodeHierarchyParents = new HashSet<TreeNodeHierarchy>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public bool IsLeaf { get; set; }
        public int? OrganisationId { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TreeNodeHierarchy> TreeNodeHierarchyChildren { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TreeNodeHierarchy> TreeNodeHierarchyParents { get; set; }
    }


public partial class TreeNodeHierarchy
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public int ChildId { get; set; }

      
        public virtual TreeNode Child { get; set; }

        public virtual TreeNode Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

And in the dbcontext class the following mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TreeNode>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("TreeNode");
                entity.Property(e => e.Code).HasMaxLength(100);
                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(255);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TreeNodeHierarchy>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("TreeNodeHierarchy");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Child)
                    .WithMany(p => p.TreeNodeHierarchyChildren)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ChildId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_TreeNodeHierarchy_TreeNode_Child");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Parent)
                    .WithMany(p => p.TreeNodeHierarchyParents)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_TreeNodeHierarchy_TreeNode_Parent");
            });
```

Here is the issue, when I write the following:

```
var nodes = _context.TreeNodes.Include(th => th.TreeNodeHierarchyChildren)
                .Where(tn => tn.IsLeaf)
                .....
```

it loads the child but not the parent.

[image]

This relation works properly in the current application (.net 4.7) using LINQ to SQL.

Am I missing something?

**Updated**

as suggested from @SpruceMoose, I included also the TreeNodeHierarchyParents property in the query but it didn't fix the issue.

```
var nodes = _context.TreeNodes
            .Include(th => th.TreeNodeHierarchyChildren)
            .Include(th => th.TreeNodeHierarchyParents)
            .Where(tn => tn.IsLeaf)
```

**Updated #2**

I applied the mapping suggested from @Dave which in my opinion it makes sense (at the end the relation is like the Windows folders/files system).
Anyway there is still something that's not working properly. When I debug the following code:

```
var nodes = _context.TreeNodes
    .Include(th => th.TreeNodeHierarchyChildren)
    .Include(th => th.TreeNodeHierarchyParents)
    .Where(tn => tn.IsLeaf)
    .ToList();
```

I still see that the parent has not been loaded

[image]

**Updated #3**

I applied the change to the query as suggested from @Moho

```
var nodes = _context.TreeNodes
    .Include(th => th.TreeNodeHierarchyChildren)
          .ThenInclude(tnhc => tnhc.Child)
    .Include(th => th.TreeNodeHierarchyParents)
          .ThenInclude(tnhp => tnhp.Parent)
    .Where(tn => tn.IsLeaf)
    .ToList();
```

and finally we got the Parent value

[image]

Now we are missing the last step, the parents of a parent

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly (eagerly) load the `Parent` elements by using an `Include()` on the `TreeNodeHierarchyParents` navigation property (as you are currently for the `TreeNodeHierarchyChildren` navigation property).

Change your linq query to the following:

```
var nodes = _context.TreeNodes
            .Include(th => th.TreeNodeHierarchyChildren)
            .Include(th => th.TreeNodeHierarchyParents)
            .Where(tn => tn.IsLeaf)
            .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your relationship mapping is wrong. You say one child has many children and one parent has many parents. It should be one child has many parents, and one parent has many children.

I think it's also a good idea to define these kinds of relationships on both sides, so that if you get something wrong it shows up as an error faster. Note also that I think some of these statements would already be the default.

Also, important, note that I think you need to use Nullable Reference Types to indicate nullability. Anything that is supposed to be nullable should have a `?` on its type name in the entity types. Though I think it's possible you should cascade delete, not set null. It depends how your model works.

Something like this, though I can't guarantee compilation:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TreeNode>(tnb => {
   tnb.ToTable("TreeNode");
   tnb.Property(tn => tn.Code).HasMaxLength(100);
   tnb.Property(tn => tn.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);

   tnb
   .HasMany(tn => tn.TreeNodeHierarchyParents)
   .WithOne(tnh => tnh.Child);

   tnb
   .HasMany(tn => tn.TreeNodeHierarchyChildren)
   .WithOne(tnh => tnh.Parent);   
});

modelBuilder.Entity<TreeNodeHierarchy>(tnhb => {
   tnhb.ToTable("TreeNodeHierarchy");

   tnhb
   .HasOne(tnh => tnh.Child)
   .WithMany(tn => tn.TreeNodeHierarchyParents)
   .HasForeignKey(tnh => tnh.ChildId)
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
   .HasConstraintName("FK_TreeNodeHierarchy_TreeNode_Child");

   tnhb
   .HasOne(tnh => tnh.Parent)
   .WithMany(tn => tn.TreeNodeHierarchyChildren)
   .HasForeignKey(tnh => tnh.ParentId)
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
   .HasConstraintName("FK_TreeNodeHierarchy_TreeNode_Parent");
});
```

One thing you can do to try to make sure your model definition is correct is to create an empty second database with it and compare its model against the real one, and then keep fine tuning it until you get it right.

Comment: I updated my question with your suggestion, please have a look at the result.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Update #2:

You’re eager loading the relationship entities of type TreeNodeHierarchy but you are not eager loading the TreeNode entities they reference.  You need to add .ThenInclude calls to do so.

```
var nodes = _context.TreeNodes
            .Include(th => th.TreeNodeHierarchyChildren)
                .ThenInclude(tnhc => tnhc.Child)
            .Include(th => th.TreeNodeHierarchyParents)
                .ThenInclude(tnhp => tnhp.Parent)
            .Where(tn => tn.IsLeaf)
```

The Child property in your example is populated in your current query because the TreeNode entity is loaded by your base query and EF Core will automatically hook it up to relevant navigation properties in other tracked entities. Thus, any “parent” that is not IsLeaf (nor any “child” that is not IsLeaf) is not loaded without the additional ThenInclude.

Another (not recommended) alternative is to enable lazy loading.

Comment: I updated my question with your suggestion, please have a look at the result.

Comment: @Francesco you'd have to use more `ThenInclude` statements to walk up the object graph but you won't know how many are needed.  Look into writing a view or stored procedure that uses a recursive CTE to return all the data you want to load, then use those results to populate your object graph

Comment: @Mogo I will have a look into a view, but in the meantime if I'd like just to add an additional ```ThenInclude``` in order to get the first Parent of a parent, how should I update the query?

Comment: why is lazy loading not recommended?

Comment: @DaveCousineau poor performance (n+1 query)

Comment: @Moho k, but that turns technically possible but avoidable performance issues into runtime errors